# IPN not receiving from paypal sandbox

Tags: php, html, paypal, sandbox

I had developed a website with online transaction using paypal as payment option.
Checkout and the shopping cart calculations on paypal side are working, but i'm not receiving any IPN messages from paypal sandbox.

```
<form name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="1234" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="merchant@domain.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com/success" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/cancel" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://domain.com/notify">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="First item"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="6.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="5.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"/>
</form>
```

The overview page in merchant paypal account shows the transactions are completed. When i click on transaction details it shows error 3004 .

Also the IPN history page does not displaying any IPN records. It says "no records found in last 24 hours" .

How can i solve this?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Will you please post the code whats is at : http://domain.com/success

Comment: Success page is an html to display something like thank you for your purchase.
In notification page there is some code to test whether any ipn is receiving or not.

Comment: Where do you make sure that the payment has been received and IPN is verified ? Post that code please/

Comment: I tried to write something to a file, and tried send email to my email address. Both not worked in cmd="_cart" mode but works fine in other example with cmd="_xclick" mode.

its using php mail("nithin@icsoft.in", "test mail", "received");
when i call the ipn url diretly by entering on browser i'm receiving the email. But not after paypal transaction.

Answer (score 1):

It can be PayPal error - see: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/instant-payment-notifications-ipn-payment-data-transfer-pdt/ipn-failing-hasn-t-been-changed?page=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1

The most iportant messages from the link above are PayPal responses:
July 18:
"I have found that the problem you are experiencing with IPN in the Sandbox is being caused by some technical issues with the PayPal system. Our engineers are currently working diligently on a solution to this problem."
and July 19:
"We are aware of this issue and our engineers are currently working on a solution. Unfortunately, i can't give you an exact timeframe when this will be done, however this should be resolved within the next days."

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue with IPN in Sandbox that's currently being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ipn is actually world-accessible (and not under localhost or a private network)

Comment: My IPN url is world-accessible  and not using localhost. I wrote code in ipn handler to check whether paypal is calling this url.

The same IPN url is working with parameter cmd="_xclick" mode and the IPN history shows that record. But when I switch to _cart mode its not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this on localhost, it wont work. IPN just works on live. And you are saying you are not getting message from paypal sandbox ? If you are working on sandbox, why are you keeping the action url for actual paypal form ?

Comment: I'm not trying it on localhost.

That was a mistake while posting my question in forum. Actually the url is set to www.sandbox.paypal.com.